# VBA Find value in range and change cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to finish this code with steps outlined below it. Any help appreciated

```
Sub Test()
Dim Value As Double

    For Each Value In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("V17:V57")
        If Value.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("V17:V57") = 0 Then...
        ...
        End If
End Sub
```

Check if 0 exists in range

If true...

- reset my 'Data Validation' Source range of cell on same worksheet that has a drop down list that depends on the new range (ie from cell Q17 down to same row where 0 value is).
  Note this Source range is located 5 columns to the left of column where 0 value is and the first row of this range is the same row (17) as where range containing 0 value starts

Else...

- find and select cell with least negative value, by using something like `Application.WorksheetFunction.FormulaArray ("MAX(IF(V17:V37<=0,V17:V37),MIN(V17:V37))")`
- once cell found/selected, perform goal seek to set selected cell to set it to 0 by changing value in cell 4 cells to left of selected cell
- Automatically update 'Data Validation' Source range as above

For when 0 exists, I'm trying this code but how can I set validation range based on a corresponding range of cells in another column of my data table? Cell H24 is where my drop down list is

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("V17:V57")
    If rng.Value = 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Select
    Range ("H24").Select
       With Selection.Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _ xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet!$V$17:$V" & ??
    Else...
```

The following code gives debug error at evaluation line.
Overall code block needs simplifying...too many If, For, Next?? I've annotated for clarity. Need help also with the goal seek line.

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("V17:V57")
    If rng.Value <> 0 Then
    rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.FormulaArray("MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))") 'this formula searches for the least min number in the range
    rng.Select
    Range("selected cell").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("cell 5 columns left of selected cell")...this line makes selected cell = 0 
    Exit For
    End If
Next rng
```

Comment: Dim rng as Range: For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("V17:V57") : If rng.Value = 0 Then.....:Else....:End If........

Comment: Not sure how to deal with the validation. As per edit to original question

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to find the value "**3**" over the range **A1:B10**:

```
Set given_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
given_range.Select
Set found_value = Selection.Find("3")
```

And if you're looking for its address:

```
value_address = found_value.Address(0,0)
```

Using the *(0,0)* at the end will return the address without any *$* (B3 instead of $B$3)

**As an extra:** if you want to know the row or the column, do as follows

```
value_column = Split(found_value.Address, "$")(1)
value_row = Split(found_value.Address, "$")(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'To check if an element is within a specific Array, Object, Range, String, etc.
Public Function isInArray(ByVal itemSearched As Variant, ByVal aArray As Variant) As Boolean
Dim item As Variant

If VarType(aArray) >= vbArray Or VarType(aArray) = vbObject Or VarType(aArray) = vbDataObject Or TypeName(aArray) = "Range" Then
    For Each item In aArray
        If itemSearched = item Then
            isInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    isInArray = False
ElseIf VarType(aArray) = vbString Then
    isInArray = InStr(1, aArray, itemSearched, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 'Comparing character by character
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    isInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(itemSearched, aArray, False)) 'Slow on large arrays
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I need to go one step back before handling this block of code. Thanks for sending. I've just edited my original question with a new block of code where I need some support please.